# Probability with 3 cars and 5 people

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 3 taxi cars waiting for 5 people. I need to find a probability that all cars won’t be empty.

I think 5 people can choose a car $3^5$ ways. Is it right?  How can I find a probability?

Comment: Is there a limit to how many people each car can hold?

Comment: No, but if all cars Couldn’t be empty, max people one car can take is 3 and then others can take only 1, or  teo cars take 2 peoples and the third one only one.

Answer (score 2):

I preassume that $5$ persons can choose for the same taxi.

Number the taxi's: $1,2,3$.

Let $T_i$ denote the event that taxi with number $i$ will be empty.

To be found is $1-P(T_1\cup T_2\cup T_3)$ and with inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:$$1-P(T_1\cup T_2\cup T_3)=1-3P(T_1)+3P(T_1\cap T_2)=1-3\left(\frac23\right)^5+3\left(\frac13\right)^5$$